# Billing API dummy transactions - Shopify

Tags: shopify

I've currently developed a Shopify app in which I'm tryiing to integrate the Billing API.
I referred the docs. 
In order to create the first test transaction, I called the POST request `https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/recurring_application_charges.json`

It returned a successfull response that contained `recurring_application_charge` JSON object. In this object, there was a field called `confirmation_url`. On hitting that URL, I received an error. It's mentioned below.

[image]

I just want to know that is this the right procedure that I'm following to test the payments? What exactly needs to be done in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So there's a parameter called test. We need to set it to true.
[Reference](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/adding-billing-to-your-app)